# tkinter variable.grid(row=0)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have started working with tkinter and I have such problems. For example,

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

theLabel = Label(root, text="bla bla")
theLabel.grid(row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

This code does not work and gives an error like that.

```
File "C:\Users\Kenan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2074, in grid_configure
    + self._options(cnf, kw))
_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @Luke.py, you can't mix `grid()` and `pack()` within the same widget.

- On line 6, you are packing a `Frame` inside `root`
- On line 9, you are griding a `Label` inside `root`

---

Perhaps you meant to `grid()` the `Label` inside the frame, in which case change line 8 to

```
theLabel = Label(frame, text="bla bla")
```

Or maybe you really do want the `Frame` and  `Label` at the same level, in which case, change line 6 to

```
frame.grid()
```

Comment: thanks guys, my mistake was frame. I should not use it. When I remove it worked. Thanks to everyone :)

Comment: If you start using ttk for more native looking controls and windows on all platforms, you will want to put a `ttk.Frame` inside every `Toplevel` to get the right (system default) colour background

Answer (score 2):

This problem arises when you use a combination of pack and grid within the same frame / root.

Change the `grid` on line 9 to `pack()`, or vise versa.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

theLabel = Label(frame, text="bla bla") *this should use frame - not root
theLabel.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

Hope this helps!
Luke

Comment: Firstly thanks for answer. But, .pack works anyway. I need to use .grid. Actually I have written some entries and I want to locate them near labels. Can you help me about this?

Comment: You changed both the `Label`'s root (from `root` to `frame`) which would've fixed it. But additionally you also changed `grid` to `pack` which isn't necessary anymore.

Comment: @xZise good spot! Thank you